# How to structure a static list of options for a dropdown that is coupled to your code?

Tags: list, enums

In the past, all my lists were put in the database. I did not know better and it seemed to me like data... so I put them in the database.

For some lists (e.g. countries), it is the right way to do it.  But for others like options that triggers a different behaviour in your code, it is not.

For instance, let's say I have a `User` object and this object has a property called `Status`. The `Status` is tightly coupled to behavious in my code:

- **Active**: you can access the application.
- **Banned**: you cannot access the application and can never reset your account.
- **Inactive**: You did not use your acccess for X months, you can fill a form to reactivate your account.

The *old me* would have created a table in the database called `UserStatus` with 
3 rows in it. The table would have looked like this:

```
+----+----------+
| Id |   Code   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | ACTIVE   |
|  2 | BAN      |
|  3 | INACTIVE |
+----+----------+
```

Then, `Code` column would have been used in my code to "bind" the user status to the right behaviour (and to the right 'display string' according to the language).  That said, editing the `Code` would have screwed everything. And adding new status in the database would have no effect as you need to add data in the database AND add code to handle the status.  This seems like the wrong way of doing things.

Then, I thought about using an `enum`.  Now, I don't have the database + code issue.  I handle everything from the code and it makes more sense as, in my opinion, it's not data that should be in a database.  But with `enum` comes this problem: in fact hey are an `int` but I need to use them as `string`.

I also thought about setting constants in the `User` object:

```
public const string Active = "ACTIVE";
public const string Ban = "BAN";
public const string Inactive = "INACTIVE";
```

But now that I have figured the right way to handle it in the code, I must display the list in the UI. It can be done with the `enum` but it requires some hacking. Samething with the constants as the list needs to be handled manually. Using the database would make that so easy... damn!

In the end, my question becomes: What is the right structure for these "static" lists that are tightly coupled with your code but also need to be displayed ?

**Update:**

Each user has one (and only one) `Status` and that `Status` can be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've contemplated the same question many, many times over the years.  Here are some [perhaps] insights that I've learned.

First, some clarification.  I assume that each user will have a Status attribute and that the value can change for each user.  In other words, the value belongs in the DB and it must be associated with each user.

#### My favorite approach in this case - store a string in the User table

My favorite approach is to create a Status column on the user table.  Since each user can only have 1 status, it makes sense to just store this detail in the User table.  Doing so has the advantage of making queries easier to write.  The reason I'd choose to store it as a string are 2:

1. `It makes perusing the DB easier.`  While debugging and just viewing raw data in the db, it's easy for developers new to the project to understand what the Status column is at a glance and it's easy to figure out the the Status of any given User row at a glance.  Making values easy to understand is of the utmost importance in my opinion when making software easy to develop/modify.
2. `I assume that duplicating this string won't become a performance/storage problem`.  Now, if you have millions and millions (maybe even hundreds of millions) of user rows, then you may want to shrink the size of this column.

And one other thing I like to do is to make sure that I use a file of constants (like what you described) and only use those constants when interacting with the DB table (for inserts/updates, that is).  That's the perfect use case for constants, and you can create easy little utility functions that ensure the value you are about to insert are in that list of constants.

#### Caveats that could change my answer, and alternative solutions

1. `You have hundreds of millions of Users`.

   - In this case, you *may* need to shrink the size of the column to save space.  You can either use an enum of some sort in the DB and limit the field to be a small varchar type of some sort or use a small int of some sort to represent the `Status`.  I'd still put that column on the `User` record to prevent extra join's in large queries.  And if you went the int route, I would handle the translation of that `int` into a string in the code and in project documentation.  Lookup tables that translate `1 to "Active"` really aren't any more helpful than a file of constants in your code that does the same thing, in my opinion.  And it just adds a join to every query that you write.  Looping through result rows in your code is generally going to be so fast that there is no performance hit either way. This caveat probably isn't even worth mentioning, but I have run into it on rare occasions.
2. `Each user can have multiple statuses.`  Well, in this case you'd need a join table of some sort.  I'd probably make the join table look like this, if possible:

   `+--------+----------+
   | UserId |   Code   |
   +--------+----------+
   |  1     | ACTIVE   |
   |  2     | BAN      |
   |  3     | INACTIVE |
   |  1     | BAN      |
   +--------+----------+`

Now I realize that your use-case doesn't really make sense for a one-to-many relationship like this.  BUT, in other use-cases where you're debating where to stick constants like this, you may run into this situation.  In these cases, I STILL like to put a string in the DB when possible.  Unless I'm really worried about saving the bits and bytes, I'll use a string.  And 99% of the time, a column like this isn't the place you're worried about saving space.  It just makes perusing the DB and learning the DB so much easier.

Anyway, just some thoughts from my experiences, hope you find them helpful!

Comment: Your answers confirms what I think.  But it does not answer the "how do you build the list for a dropdown ?". And also where do you build it ? It's easy to use the constant in a controller (if MVC app)... but what if I need a WebApi project now ? Do I need to copy/paste the code to rebuild the list again ?

Comment: I'm happy to know I'm not the only one that has this question. I do like strings too. I'm not worried, in most projects, about costs of storing such a little string (compared to having to link to another table when I think I should not).

Comment: No, don't copy/paste the code.  I would probably just create a function somewhere the gives me the list of the options.  You should probably put that function in the same file as the constants themselves if you can.  

I'm not sure exactly what programming language/framework you're using, so I can't give you an exact example, but I do this sort of thing in PHP and Node.js all the time.

Comment: Don't worry, I don't need an example! I was about to create a static function inside the `User`class to get the values. Maybe that would be the easiest way of doing it, be at a logicial location and simple to manage in the long run.

Comment: Exactly!  Sounds like a good way to go to me.  If you're server-side rendering HTML, then you could loop through that list in your html template-builder (if you're using a templating language).  If you're using a single-page app (like Angular, React, Marionette, etc.), you could just return the list as data to the front-end and build the dropdown on the frontend using your frontend framework